# Connect Table Cells from Different Rows with Diagonal line

Tags: html, css, tabular

I'm looking to have diagonal lines connecting table cells from different rows.  I can easily get a diagonal line to connect the corners of a single cell, but is there a way to cross cells?

For example, in the image below, I'd like to have diagonal lines connecting "1 and "3" to the "1 & 3" cell.  Same thing with 2, 5, and 2 & 5.

[image: table1]

Of course, this is just one variation.  I would like to be able to connect any number of cells in any way.  Maybe something like this...

[image: table2]

Any ideas here?

Comment: I think you'll need absolute positioned elements for that.

Comment: You cannot do this using plain HTML. U will have to use SVG or something

Comment: Canvas might also work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Demo : [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ohdwc)

I added one more demo, which will take only the cell positions and based on that it will automatically find the positions and connect them accordingly.

It is better than the other answer, in which we need to provide the line start and end points.

**HTML Code**

```
<br>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>+</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>+</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.line {
    width : 2px;
    background-color : red;
    display : block;
    position : absolute;
    -webkit-transform-origin : 0 0;
    transform-origin : 0 0;
}
.green {
    background-color : green;
}
.blue {
    background-color : blue;
}
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
$(function() {
    connectCells($('table'), {x : 0, y : 0}, {x : 1, y : 1}, 'red');
    connectCells($('table'), {x : 2, y : 0}, {x : 1, y : 1}, 'blue');
});

function connectCells(table, cell1, cell2, cls) {
    var td1 = table.find('tr:eq(' + cell1.y + ') td:eq(' + cell1.x + ')');
    var td2 = table.find('tr:eq(' + cell2.y + ') td:eq(' + cell2.x + ')');

    var pos1 = $(td1).position();
    var pos2 = $(td2).position();
    drawLine({
        x : pos1.left + $(td1).outerWidth()/2,
        y : pos1.top + $(td1).outerHeight() - 5
    }, {
        x : pos2.left + $(td2).outerWidth()/2,
        y : pos2.top + $(td2).outerHeight() - 5
    }, cls);
}


function drawLine(tp1, tp2, cls) {

   if(!cls) { cls = "" };

   if(tp2.x < tp1.x && tp2.y < tp1.y) {
      p1 = tp2;
      p2 = tp1;
   } else {
      p1 = tp1;
      p2 = tp2;
   }

   var ang = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
   var lin = $('<span></span>').addClass("line " + cls).appendTo('body');

   $(lin).css({
      'top' : p1.y,
      'left' : p1.x,
      'height' : Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x)* (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y)),
      'transform' : 'rotate(' + ang + 'deg)'
   });
}
```

Comment: Updated proper CodePen URL in the answer. Please check now.

Comment: Wow!  This is very nice.  I'm a bit confused on how to work it though.  If I wanted to connect "1" and "4" to "5" (because 1 + 4 = 5), how could I do this?

Comment: We only need to pass the cell position inside the table. For selecting first cell we need to use 0,0. Because it is first row first cell. For selecting cell with number - 5, we use 1,1. Because it is in second row second cell. Currently indices are 0-based. But we can update this for 1-based indices. So, to select cell with 4 we use 2,0 because it is in first row third cell.

Comment: Is this helpful or it need any modifications?

Comment: That works great!  Thank you very much!  You've come up with something very versatile here that is easy to implement and can be adapted for various uses.  I wish I could give more than 1 upvote. :)

Comment: I've been working on fully implementing this and I found a bug.  I need to put this in a table row that has display set to "none". Then when a button is clicked the display for that row is set to "block".  However, all of the calculations for position and rotation get messed up due to the `display: none;`  Any ideas on this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34735/discussion-between-vanga-sasidhar-and-gtilflm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yjmRY/)

**JavaScript Code**

```
$(function() {
    var p = { x : 200, y : 200 },
        p1 = { x : 300, y : 150 },
        p2 = { x : 200, y : 100 },
        p3 = { x : 100, y : 150 };

    drawLine(p, p1);
    drawLine(p, p2, "green");
    drawLine(p, p3, "blue");
});


function drawLine(tp1, tp2, cls) {

    if(!cls) { cls = "" };

    if(tp2.x < tp1.x && tp2.y < tp1.y) {
        p1 = tp2;
        p2 = tp1;
    } else {
        p1 = tp1;
        p2 = tp2;
    }

    var ang = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
    var lin = $('<span></span>').addClass("line " + cls).appendTo('body');

    $(lin).css({
        'top' : p1.y,
        'left' : p1.x,
        'height' : Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x)* (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y)),
        'transform' : 'rotate(' + ang + 'deg)'
    });
}
```

**CSS Code**

```
.line {
    width : 2px;
    background-color : red;
    display : block;
    position : absolute;
    -webkit-transform-origin : 0 0;
    transform-origin : 0 0;
}
.green {
    background-color : green;
}
.blue {
    background-color : blue;
}
```

It will create a new span and position it at the given co-ordinates using CSS3 transform.

You can find the start and end positions dynamically and pass them to draw lines with optional colors.

You can enhance this as per your needs.

Comment: This looks great Vanga!  Thanks a lot.  

Is there a way to start the 0, 0 coordinate somewhere other than the upper-left corner of the page though?  Maybe the 0, 0 coordinate could be the upper left corner of a <div> that is inside a table for example.  Here's what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/yjmRY/1/

Comment: Yes, we can do that. We are making the line span absolute. So, to make it relative to a `div`, we need to add the span inside that `div` and we need to make sure that `div` has position - relative. This will make the line relative from the `div` instead of the page. Need a demo? Let me know.

Comment: I think I've done what you described here (http://jsfiddle.net/yjmRY/2/).  I've also adapted the code a bit.  The only thing I need now is to make the <br> tag the height of 1 px, or something like that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check my other answer, which takes only cell positions and it connects the cells automatically. I think this new answer is better than this and we don't bother about exact positions. Let me know if the span's relative position is an issue.

Comment: Any luck with the new answer?